# При использовании таймера не передается название домена из формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#addForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    registr();
  });
})

function registr() {
  var data = $("#addForm").serialize()
  $.ajax({
    url: '/script.php',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      $('.progress').show();
      $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#addForm').find('input[type=text]').val('');
      $('.alert-info').show();
      timer(data);
    }
  });

  function timer(site) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('progress');
    elem.value = parseInt(elem.value) + 1;
    if (elem.value < 1) {
      window.setTimeout(timer, 1000);
    } else {
      $('.progress').hide();
      $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.alert-info').hide();
      var url = "/project/" + site + "/";
      $(location).attr('href', url);
    }
  }
}
```

Если устанавливают **if(elem.value < 10)** то в переменную site передается undefined и перекидывает на /project/undefined/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете в `setTimeout` ссылку на функцию `timer`. Движок javascript-a, естественно, не знает, с какими параметрами ее вызывать и вызывает без параметров.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ timer(site); }, 1000);
```

или

```
window.setTimeout(timer.bind(window, site), 1000);
```

или, как справедливо указал @Grundy,

```
window.setTimeout(timer, 1000, site);
```

Может Вы имели в виду делать прогресс видимым *до* вызова `$.ajax`?

Comment: лучше: `window.setTimeout(timer, 1000, site)` - лишняя функция не создается

Comment: @Grundy а, да, постоянно вылетает из головы, что в `setTimeout` можно сразу и параметры указать